# JMeter Report Dashboard Error - Data Exporter "html" is unable to export data

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to build a report dashboard from a .csv that was generated by a performance test script that I've ran on Jmeter but it does not work. Examining JMeter.log file I could notice that the template files could not be processed, but I do not understand why.

Have anyone here faced this issue? Do anyone know how to solve it?

See the log lines below:

```
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\user.properties 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\system.properties 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2016 The Apache Software Foundation 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 3.0 r1743807 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_25 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows 7 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=x86 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.1 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Max memory     =1060372480 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Available Processors =4 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 10.234.11.16 Name: WSPDBB33106 FullName: WSPDBB33106.corporate.int 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Setting property 'jmeter.reportgenerator.outputdir' to:'C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\examples\ReportTest"' 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator: ReportGenerator will use for Parsing the separator:',' 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator: Will only generate report from results file:C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\examples\CSVSample.csv 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator: Reading report generator properties from:C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\reportgenerator.properties 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator: Merging with JMeter properties 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.temp_dir" not found, using default value "temp" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold" not found, using default value "500" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold" not found, using default value "1500" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.sample_filter" not found, using default value "null" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title" not found, using default value "null" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimePercentiles.exclude_controllers" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimesOverTime.exclude_controllers" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.bytesThroughputOverTime.exclude_controllers" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.activeThreadsOverTime.exclude_controllers" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.timeVsThreads.exclude_controllers" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimeDistribution.exclude_controllers" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.latenciesOverTime.exclude_controllers" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.transactionsPerSecond.exclude_controllers" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.filters_only_sample_series" not found, using default value "true" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter" not found, using default value "" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Property "jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.show_controllers_only" not found, using default value "false" instead. 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer: Using format:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS to parse timeStamp field 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AggregateConsumer#stopProducing(): beginDate produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AggregateConsumer#stopProducing(): endDate produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.ApdexSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): apdexSummary produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.RequestsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): requestsSummary produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.StatisticsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): statisticsSummary produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.ErrorsSummaryConsumer#stopProducing(): errorsSummary produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyVSRequestGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): latencyVsRequest produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.HitsPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): hitsPerSecond produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.CodesPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): codesPerSecond produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeVSRequestGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimeVsRequest produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): startIntervalControlerFilter produced 60 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimePercentilesGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimePercentiles produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimesOverTime produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.BytesThroughputGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): bytesThroughputOverTime produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ActiveThreadsGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): activeThreadsOverTime produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TimeVSThreadGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): timeVsThreads produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeDistributionGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): responseTimeDistribution produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.LatencyOverTimeGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): latenciesOverTime produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.TransactionsPerSecondGraphConsumer#stopProducing(): transactionsPerSecond produced 0 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.FilterConsumer#stopProducing(): nameFilter produced 144 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.AbstractSampleConsumer: class org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.NormalizerSampleConsumer#stopProducing(): normalizer produced 36 samples 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.CsvFileSampleSource: produce(): 12 samples produced in 251ms on channel 0 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator: Exporting data using exporter:'html' of className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter' 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter: Will generate dashboard in folder:C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\examples\ReportTest" 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 INFO  - jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter: Report will be generated in:C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\examples\ReportTest", creating folder structure 
2016/06/10 15:51:42 ERROR - jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator: Data exporter "html" is unable to export data. org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ExportException: Unable to process template files.
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter.export(HtmlTemplateExporter.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:348)
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:256)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:478)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\examples\ReportTest"
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:2384)
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter.export(HtmlTemplateExporter.java:483)
    ... 8 more

2016/06/10 15:51:42 FATAL - jmeter.JMeter: An error occurred:  org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Data exporter "html" is unable to export data.
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:357)
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:256)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:478)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
Caused by: org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ExportException: Unable to process template files.
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter.export(HtmlTemplateExporter.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:348)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\examples\ReportTest"
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(FileUtils.java:2384)
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter.export(HtmlTemplateExporter.java:483)
    ... 8 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the stacktrace you show :

> Unable to create directory C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\examples\ReportTest

Ensure JMeter has the rights to create and write in the folder "C:\tmp_Vinicius\Tools\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\examples\"

Comment: Wow, that was the problem indeed and it was right in front of my eyes. I'm sorry about that. I did not pay attention to the last lines, maybe because I'm too tired today. Thanks a lot